# Visual Studio - Xamarin - Show "Document Outline"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm starting out with Xamarin and am finding Visual Studio to have many pitfalls :(

I clicked the "X" button on the left/right hand side tabs and they've vanished ... now I can't find how to recover them!

How can I show the "Solution", "Document Outline", "Unit Tests", "Toolbox" & "Properties" tabs in the following situation (as I'm about to reinstall the software :/)

[image]

Comment: look under View --> Pads

Comment: My Hero!!! I found SO posts but were for an older VS distro ... thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, look at the image below.

[image: Place to find]

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version of Visual Studio (Enterprise 2017) it has moved a little bit.

It is now under: View -> Other Windows -> Document Outline

Or you can use the shortcut Ctrl+W, U